# Docker exec in docker windows

Tags: windows, docker

I'm having trouble with running

```
 `docker `exec -t sandbox /bin/sh -c 'echo "127.0.0.1 sandbox" >> /etc/hosts'
```

in windows docker. I keep getting the following error:

```
"The system cannot find the path specified"
```

Does anyone know why I am getting the error?

Answer (score 10):

instead of 
`docker exec -it [containerid] /bin/sh`

try to use  
`docker exec -it [containerid] //bin//sh`

Comment: Can you add an explanation of why this helps in this case?

Comment: It works, but we still would like an explanation.

Comment: worked like a charm in `git bash`

Answer (score 3):

I found out that using `"` instead of `'` fixes this:

```
docker exec -t sandbox /bin/sh -c "echo '127.0.0.1 sandbox' >> /etc/hosts"
```

Answer (score 1):

I'd run `docker ps` to get the ID of your running container then do 
`docker exec that_id /bin/bash`

Answer (score -3):

I'm using `docker exec -it [containerid] /bin/sh`

Comment: If you're going to add an answer, please consider also adding some details and explanation to it. "I'm using this" doesn't per say help community members understand why should they try a proposal and how it would help them.

Comment: Thanks for the info.  Will keep this in mind next time i make a comment.